# How to fix bugs in a legacy application without profound refactoring first?

Tags: refactoring

There is a mid-size legacy application (20K LoC, 150 java classes). The quality of design and code is very low, no unit tests, no documentation. However it works.

You're hired to maintain the application. There is a list of very specific properly-reported bugs. It's very difficult to understand how to fix them. Time is limited, you should start solving these bugs within a few weeks (you simply don't have time for a profound refactoring first). How to do this?

Comment: One bug at a time?  This seems more suited to programmers...

Answer (score 2):

Start with the first bug.  Maybe the easiest, maybe the highest-priority.  Whatever makes sense for your shop.

**Don't fix it.**

Instead, figure out why it's not working correctly.  From your description, it's not likely to be in some neat, nice, unit-testable method; it's probably deep in some convoluted logic somewhere.  Find it.

**Don't fix it.**

Work out a way to extract the culprit.  Maybe it's [Extract Method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html); maybe it's [Extract Class](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html); maybe some other technique will help.  But get it out there, independent of other code.  Still failing, just easier to work with.  Now, write a test that demonstrates the failure.

**OK, *now* fix it.**

What have you done?  You've isolated the problem, fixed it, made a small section of your code easier to work it, and begun to get test coverage in place.

Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: If one repeats this process endlessly, what you get seems to me to be code organized around the bugs that were fixed.  That seems like a very strange goal.

Comment: Hardly strange.  The hot spots, the failures, the known weaknesses in your code are fixed and cleaned up.

Comment: And what about the clock that's ticking away along side?

Comment: That clock - that ticking time bomb, if you prefer - ticks.  While it ticks, you can (a) undertake a massive refactoring and hope you get done in time or (b) take an incremental approach that focuses on what you know is broken and makes your code better every step of the way.  Easy choice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have a good situation.

I'd start by "refactoring" the job, first.  Make it clear to your boss that the situation is very difficult. You should also make it clear that since you weren't responsible for making the mess, that he needs to commit now to not making you responsible for not succeeding, but that you will give it a best effort. If he isn't willing to make that commitment up front under the circumstances, *then* I'd find another job.

Now the question is how to proceed. No matter what you do, you have find the problems in the code, and make it easier to do so as you go along.

First, you'll have to skim the code and get some sense of structure.  Whereever you think you understand something, insert a comment; where you don't and it matters, insert a comment with a question.   If you can, add an assertion.   Where these new assertions break, if they are easy to fix do so; if not, you can triage them by simply removing them or turning them into a question-comment.    These comments, questions and assertions will at least record the low level details of what you (don't) understand.

I would also get a tool that will let you apply *rename* refactorings *reliably* (emphasis on the latter: you can't have these breaking the code worse than it is).  Renaming furiously and religiously will help stabilize the vocabulary both for the code, and for you, and get rid of bad names.  And you can do this while skimming/working on the code, at very little cost in time, and big payoff in readability.

To *find* the (potential) source of the bugs, I'd use a test coverage tool.  Such a tool tells you what code got executed when you run a "test".   Using such a tool creatively, you can run a "test" (manual or automated, as practical) which exercises a bug; the code lit up the by test coverage tool must contain the bug somewhere.  You can run other "tests" which do not exhibit the bug; the code they execute which is common with the bug trace likely does not contain the bug.

An issue there is how can you compute this "difference" in the executed code?   Some test coverage tools will help you determine this.   My company (Semantic Designs) offers these: [Test Coverage tools for many languages](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage) that do precisely this.  Normally test coverage vectors are used to display your code with overlays showing the coverage. Our tools will let you process independent test coverage sets: intersected, diff'd, union'ed, etc. to understand the relation between the tests that produce the vectors, and display those  results displayed superimpmosed over you code.  This way you can directly see the diff between the test coverage vector for the bug, and test coverage for non-bugs.

Once you have an idea where the bug is, put more assertions into the relevant code and run the bug-generating test again.  The ones that trigger are indicators you getting close.

I'd initially avoid problems that required serious code refactoring to fix, since you are under time pressure.  (You obviously can't know that very well until after you have sense of where the problem is; exploration is an unavoidable cost).  To the extent that you can fix some of the problems early, you will buy political points.  You can use them to gain more time, and therefore the opportunity to refactor more.